# Build Failed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processFlavorUnsignedDebugAndroidTestResources'.

> Directory '/Users/app/build/intermediates/data-binding-layout-out/androidTest/flavorUnsigned/debug' specified for property 'resDir' does not exist.

Comment: can you post your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Close your existing project and re-import, hope this will solve your problem.